# Django: Many2Many Relationship During Pre_Save Signal?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-mptt

Let's assume we have the following class:

**Class 'Config'**

```
class Config(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, editable=True, blank=False, null=False)
    nodes = models.ManyToManyField(HierarchyNode_MPTT)
    element = models.ForeignKey(ForecastConfigurationLayout, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None)
```

The `nodes` attribute represents an M:N relationship. I want to default the `elements` attribute based on the combination of `nodes`. So, during the save process (ideally `pre_save`) I need to pass all the nodes to a class/method that returns a `uuid` for `element`.

So, I go to the admin application, create an object of type `Config`, select my nodes on the screen and hit save. Now, the system should call a class/method, pass the nodes and update `element` with the `uuid`. This doesn't work, because of the M:N relationship in the mapping table between `Class` and `Nodes` does not yet have the correct entries (because it's `pre_save`). I would like to avoid `post_save` because then the `nodes` attribute needs to allow `Null` values.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `m2m_changed` signal on `post_add` action. Working fine for my use case.